# URL routing - Missing slash in the end of the URL gave a 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a webapp (based on Spring MVC) that is deployed on `/mobile` (details below). The question is:

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/mobile/` or `http://localhost:8080/mobile/index`, everything is working fine.

But when I go to `http://localhost:8080/mobile` (notice the missing slash in the end), I get a 404 error. Why is that (and how do I get it fixed)?

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>mobileServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mobile-servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>mobileServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/mobile/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MobileAppController {
  @RequestMapping({"", "/", "/index"})
  public String index() {
    return "/mobile/index";
  }
}
```

Comment: using `http://localhost:8080/mobile` will be treated as default Tomcat's web-app run and it will going to serach a pah `/mobile` in `localhost:8080/` which if it could not found, throws a `404` back..

Comment: see your url <url-pattern>/mobile/*</url-pattern> here is salash at the end remove this salash.

Comment: According to the [servlet spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-2_5-mrel2-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1335553948_36539a0654f13fc919f491f0f2cdde52), the url `/mobile` should go to `mobileServlet` (see example in section 11.2.2)

Comment: Ofcourse not @ryanprayogo.. See your own mapping. It is `/mobile/*`, and in fact the path `/mobile` will be search on context of `http://localhost:8080/` which it could not find.

Answer (score 0):

He has given **`/mobile/*`** in the url pattern tag.

if he gives `localhost:8080/mobile` then he cannot access because their is no matching url.

Try By giving **`/mobile*`** in url pattern.. I think it ll work.